# angular function returning trusted html

Tags: html, angularjs, binding

Can I define function that returns trusted html and use it without `ng-bind-html`?

```
<script>
   ...
   $scope.trustedHTML = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>!</strong>');
      }
</script>
....
{{ trustedHTML() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, man, it's not possible. 
There's a good reference for `$sce` at [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/09/10/a-journey-with-trusted-html-in-angularjs.aspx)